# Modify bash string

Tags: string, bash

I am new in bash and need help in this problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

str="This Is My Bash String"
mod="-val"

# Loop through characters of str. If index is 0, insert mod at position 0. And if the current index contains space (" "), then insert mod after the space.

echo -e str
# This should output: -valThis -valIs -valMy -valBash -valString
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
for word in $str
do echo -n " $mod$word"
done
```

Comment: This is not the recommended way to split a string. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/918931/7939871 `IFS=' ' read -ra words <<< "$str"; for word in "${words[@]}"; do` …

Answer (score 7):

With bash and [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
echo "$mod${str// / $mod}"
```

Output:

```
-valThis -valIs -valMy -valBash -valString
```

Answer (score 1):

This might also do the job:

```
echo $mod$str |sed -e "s/ / $mod/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to parameter expansion:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str="This Is My Bash String"
mod="-val"

# Split string words into an array
IFS=' ' read -ra splitstr <<<"$str"

# Print each element of array, prefixed by $mod
printf -- "$mod%s " "${splitstr[@]}"
printf \\n
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
build_command_line() {
  local -ar tokens=(${@:2})
  printf '%s\n' "${tokens[*]/#/"$1"}"
}
```

Now let’s test it a bit:

```sh
mod='-val'
str='This Is My Bash String'

build_command_line "$mod" "$str"
build_command_line "$mod" $str
build_command_line "$mod" "$str" Extra Tokens
build_command_line "$mod" $str 'Extra Tokens'
```

To “modify” `str`, as you specify, just reassign it:

```sh
str="$(build_command_line "$mod" "$str")"
printf '%s\n' "$str"
```